# not equal is c++ (if else statements)

Tags: c++, console-application

Problem is that i dont know what i am doing wrong here...

i need to get if a = 1 cout is "pasirinkai fizika..."
and if a != 1 cout is "nieko nepasirinkai..."

here is code:

```
    cout << "Pasirinkimai:                                parasyk skaiciu... \n";

    cout << "1  ---- Skaiciuoti fizika 9 klasiai...\n";
    cin >> a;
    std::getchar();

    if (a = 1) {
        cout << "pasirinkai fizika...";
    }
    else if (a != 1) {
        cout << "nieko nepasirinkai...";
    }
    std::getchar();
```

When i type 2 for example it says that "pasirinkai fizika..."
and as i said before it should say "nieko nepasirinkai..."

Comment: `a = 1` should be `a == 1`.

Comment: `a` is convertible to type `bool`, `a = 1` will presumably always evaluate to true but you never gave us `a`'s type.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't warn you for this, you should increase the warning level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is an assignmenet operator, you are looking for equality operator `==` e.g. `if (a == 1)`.

Many languages use this `C` notation, you might need to get used to it.